# VBA - Typing into ListBox on User Form, handling backspaces

Tags: vba, listbox

I have a ListBox on a user form that I want the user to be able to type numerical values into the 3rd column of. The first two columns will have some predefined values in, and I want the user to select the row they want to modify, then type the number into the 3rd column.

I made the following code:

```
Private Sub cardList_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim curSel As Single
curSel = cardList.ListIndex
Dim curString As String
Dim newString As String

If curSel = -1 Then Exit Sub
If IsNull(cardList.List(curSel, 2)) Then
    curString = ""
Else
    curString = cardList.List(curSel, 2)
End If
If KeyCode > 47 And KeyCode < 58 Then
    newString = curString & Chr(KeyCode)
ElseIf KeyCode = 8 Then
    If Not curString = "" Then
        newString = Mid(curString, 1, Len(curString) - 1)
    End If
End If

cardList.List(curSel, 2) = newString
End Sub
```

This code works fine, the only problem is that when I press backspace the last character of the string is deleted as it should, but the selection of the ListBox also jumps up to the first row for some reason. Is there any way to prevent this? Or is there a better way to have a listbox that the user can type into?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the Listbox.  You can use `KeyCode = 0` to cancel the Key and prevent this from happening.

```
Private Sub cardList_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim curSel As Single
    curSel = cardList.ListIndex
    Dim curString As String
    Dim newString As String

    If curSel = -1 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNull(cardList.List(curSel, 2)) Then
        curString = ""
    Else
        curString = cardList.List(curSel, 2)
    End If
    If KeyCode > 47 And KeyCode < 58 Then
        newString = curString & Chr(KeyCode)
    ElseIf KeyCode = 8 Then
        If Not curString = "" Then
            newString = Mid(curString, 1, Len(curString) - 1)
        End If
        KeyCode = 0
    End If

    cardList.List(curSel, 2) = newString
End Sub
```